# Hi am unable to import contact object library and import method from apex class to LWC

Tags: javascript, import, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

Hi am trying to import contact object from schema library and import method from apex class into LWC , the LWC component is being deployed but DML operation isnt getting displayed,

Highlighted lines are throwing warning [Light colour is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQbpe.jpg)

Please help down below is the code

```
import { LightningElement , track} from 'lwc';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact'; //problematic lines
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import TITLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Title';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
import CreateCon from '@salesforce/apex/ContactCreation.CreateCon'; //problematic lines
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
```

am trying to add records to contacts using LWC